# Когда используются собственные домены приложений?

Tags: c#, .net

Прочитал про домены приложений и немного не понял, при каких обстоятельствах следует грузить сборки в отдельный домен.

Как я понял, по функционалу это похоже на стандартную динамическую загрузку библеотек(позднее связывание), но с одним отличием- домены изолированы между собой и для взаимодействия нужно использовать какой-либо протокол взаимодейсвтия (Например, WCF).

Я правильно понимаю, что это что-то типа: Приложения, которое содержит в себе N-ое кол-во других изолированных приложений?

Comment: Домены нужно использовать, если возникает необходимость в выгрузке сборок. Сборку невозможно выгрузить из приложения. Но если её загрузить в домен, то можно выгрузить весь домен целиком.

Comment: для взаимодействия доменов нужно прописать экспортируемые и импортируемые интерфейсы, если использовать MEF, или делать полную обвязку MAF, оба варианта почти равнозначны в настоящее время и поддерживаются самим .NET без использования сторонних библиотек. Собственно по именам MEF и MAF  и нужно искать документацию. Ну и еще один момент, все импортируемые/экспортируемые типы обязаны поддерживать маршалинг по значению либо ссылке, иначе получите букет исключений. Также через границы доменов не работает рефлексия, GetType()  будет всегда возвращать MarshalByRefObject для ссылочных типов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть несколько сценариев, при которых нужны домены.

Например, это выполнение кода непонятного происхождения. Если ваше приложение грузит плагин из интернета, то в нём может оказаться враждебный код. Вы можете вынести его в другой домен с урезанными правами, чтобы он не имел доступа к файловой системе, P/Invoke или рефлексии.

Далее, если код не злонамеренный, но просто «падучий», то опять-таки есть смысл выгрузить его в отдельный домен, чтобы при падении он не «утащил» за собой главное приложение.

Следующий сценарий упомянут @Alexander Petrov в комментарии: вы не можете выгрузить загруженную сборку, но можете выгрузить целый домен. Выгрузка сборки может быть нужна, чтобы удалить файл с ней (например, вы хотите загрузить новую версию плагина).

Ещё один сценарий — вы можете таким образом избавиться от очень большого статического объекта. (С точки зрения языка статический объект живёт вечно, но на самом деле он будет выгружен вместе с доменом.)

Comment: А можете так же описать в чем проявляется изолированность?  Т.е я могу загрузить сборку в другой домен, вызвать какие-нибудь методы, но никакие возвращаемые данные я получить не смогу?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ну, если вы создаёте другой домен, вы можете вызвать в нём метод и протащить результат через границу домена. Изоляция в том, что (1) если домен упадёт, то при этом ваше приложение продолжит бежать, (2) вы можете урезать ему права, и он не сможет работать с вашим доменом, даже если захочет.